# How to change configuration GTSon (i.e. for individual node have different GTS request) at command line in Castalia 3.3 Simulator?

Tags: c

I'm executing BANtest experiment provided in simulation example in Castalia 3.3 simulator. I'm exploring GTS in Contention Free Period (CFP) under beacon enable mode of IEEE 802.15.4 MAC. I want to change the configuration i.e. GTSon such a way that each individual node requests different GTS slots at command line. What do i need to change in configuration file ?

I read and understand the procedure to change configuration at command line from "section 3.5.3" at castalia user's manual. Currently, i'm able to change "equal" GTS request made by nodes in GTSon configuration at command line, but i am interested to get different GTS slots request form individual node.

---

## Case-1: code for equal GTS request form all nodes

```
# Define as set of equal GTS request for all nodes in omnetpp.ini
  [Config GTSon]
    SN.node[*].Communication.MAC.requestGTS = ${GTS=1,2}


# Execute BANtest example- take request GTS from config file
  $ Castalia -c ZigBeeMAC,[GTSon] 

# Changing configuration (i.e. GTSon) form command line-run successfully
  $ Castalia -c GTSon=\$\{GTS=0,3\}
```

---

## Case-2: code for different GTS requests form nodes

```
# Define differnt GTS requests for nodes in omnetpp.ini
  [Config GTSon]
    SN.node[1].Communication.MAC.requestGTS = ${GTS1=0}
    SN.node[2].Communication.MAC.requestGTS = ${GTS2=4}
    SN.node[3].Communication.MAC.requestGTS = ${GTS3=3}
    SN.node[4].Communication.MAC.requestGTS = ${GTS4=0}
    SN.node[5].Communication.MAC.requestGTS = ${GTS5=0}


# Execute BANtest example- run successfully
  $ Castalia -c ZigBeeMAC,[GTSon] 

# Changing configuration (i.e.GTSon) form command line- showing error
  $ Castalia -c GTSon=\$\{GTS1=0,GTS2=1,GTS3=5,GTS4=0,GTS5=0\}
```

The case-1 is running successfully, but case-2 have error,which is given below:

"ERROR: configuration 'GTSon' has more than one parameter and cannot be used with '=' syntax"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is simply a limitation of the Castalia script. Castalia's User manual is explicit about this limitation **in section 3.5.3**. You can also search for this string: `has more than one parameter and cannot be used with '=' syntax"` in the Castalia script to find out more details, or to think about how you could extend it to support multiple cmdline parameters per configuration.

But an extension of functionality is not really needed. One simple workaround would be to define individual configurations for each node. For example

```
 [Config GTSon-n1]
   SN.node[1].Communication.MAC.requestGTS = ${GTS1=0}

 [Config GTSon-n2]
   SN.node[2].Communication.MAC.requestGTS = ${GTS2=4}
...
```

Then you can use Castalia to run

```
  $ Castalia -c ZigBeeMAC,GTSon-n1,GTSon-n2
```

Or change the parameter in the cmdline

```
  $ Castalia -c ZigBeeMAC,GTSon-n1=3,GTSon-n2=5
```

In general, I'd like to suggest that changing the simulation parameters at command line is not a good idea (at least for your regular simulations). You should only use this feature to run throwaway exploratory simulations, where you quickly want to test the effect of a change, without having to edit the ini file. The added bonus here is that the command line is saved with the output file so you have some trace of how this output file was produced. That's why this feature was added in Castalia. However, for your regular simulations studies, you should have the parameter values (or range of values) in the ini file itself. In this way there is a proper record of what the simulation study is supposed to be. OMNeT++ ini files are quite versatile, and you can achieve a lot of with their syntax. Make sure you know about all that OMNeT has to offer by reading [chapter 9 of the OMNeT++ 4.x manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp4/manual/usman.html#sec329).